# How to remove a word if it has more than 2 occurrence of a given character in python?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am parsing a log file which has lines like:

```
Pushing the logs into /var/log/my_log.txt
Pushing the logs into /opt/test/log_file.txt
```

There are multiple occurrences of these lines with auto-generated paths(/.../.../...)

I want to change this into a generic form like:

```
 Pushing the logs into PATH
```

I tried using regex to select a word with multiple forward slashes and then replace it with the word 'PATH' as follows:

```
line = re.sub(r'\b([\/A-Z]*\/[A-Z]*){1,}\b',' PATH ',line)
```

Only the forward slashes are getting replaced but not the entire word.

Very new to this concept. Am I doing something wrong? All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try, ``re.sub("/.*", 'PATH', line)``

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
import re

line = 'Pushing the logs into /var/log/my_log.txt'

pat = r'(?<!\S)(/\S+){2,}'

line = re.sub(pat, 'PATH', line)

print(line)
```

This is not answering exactly as stated because it looks for "words" that must **start** with a `/` and also contain **two** or more `/` (with other non-whitespace characters following each `/`) -- so it would cover e.g. `/tmp/my_log.txt`.  I think this better covers the sort of strings that you would find -- if they are absolute paths then `/` will always be the first character, and similarly if they are files rather than directories then the last `/` will not be at the end (although I haven't bothered to *exclude* a `/` at the end provided that there are also at least two before it).  If you only want to look for e.g. 3 or more `/` (not at the end), then change the 2 to a 3, but you will miss `/tmp/my_log.txt` if you do that.

The first bit of the regexp `(?<!\S)` is a negative lookbehind assertion meaning "not preceded by a non-whitespace character", i.e. it will match at the start of a "word" or the start of the line.  The next bit `(/\S+)` means a `/` followed by one or more non-whitespace characters (which *could* include `/` -- it doesn't matter so I haven't bothered to exclude these).  And the `{2,}` means that there should be two or more of these.

(I am using "word" here as in the question, to refer to sequence of non-whitespace characters, not necessarily letters.)

Answer (score 0):

Only the forward slashes are matched because the string is lower case, and the pattern matches zero or more times either a forward slash or uppercase char A-Z using `[\/A-Z]*`

You could make the pattern case insensitive using `re.IGNORECASE` but it will not match the underscore and the dot in the example data.

The first forward slash does not get matched as you start the pattern with a word boundary `\b`, but there is no word boundary between the space and the  first forward slash.

A bit more specific match could be using `\w` to match a word character and specify the dot for the extension:

```
(?<!\S)(?:/\w+)+/\w+\.\w+(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?:/\w+)+` Match 1 or more times a `/` followed by 1+ word chars
- `/\w+\.\w+` Match the last `/` followed by a filename format using the dot and word chars
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Va40wq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fylBBN)

```
import re

line = 'Pushing the logs into /var/log/my_log.txt'
line = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(?:/\w+)+/\w+\.\w+(?!\S)', 'PATH', line)
print(line)
```

Output

```
Pushing the logs into PATH
```

---

A broader pattern could be matching 2 times the forward slash and use a negated character class to match any char except a forward slash or a newline

```
(?<!\S)(?:/[^/\r\n]+){2,}
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y3sJ2c/1)